# Node-inspector - can't set local variables - is node inspector broken?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I'm using node-inspector. I have run debugger, and the console is paused where the debugger has started:

```
> var z = 1
undefined

> z
ReferenceError: z is not defined
```

Setting globals seems to work:

```
> a = 1
1
> a
1
```

[image]

Is node-inspector broken or an I doing something wrong?

I am using node-inspector 0.5, which is the latest at the time I'm writing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Node Inspector.*

This is a missing feature of Node Inspector.

Local variables are preserved in Chrome Developer Tools, thus it should be possible to get this working in Node Inspector too.

Please fill an issue in project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open).

Screenshot of Chrome Developer Tools:

[image: Screenshot of Developer Tools]

Comment: Thanks for the response Miroslav! Filed at https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/230.